# How to make a property/method invokable or not?

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

I want to achieve this functionality:

1. I have an object `var obj = {};`
2. I have three properties on that obj, `obj.zero` & `obj.one`& `obj.binaryString`

   - `obj.zero` & `obj.one` are methods while `obj.binaryString` is a string

When I chain the properties, I want them to add their respective digit to the `binaryString`.  So for example:

`obj.one.zero.zero.one` => makes `obj.binaryString` = `1001`

`obj.one.zero.one.one.zero` => makes `obj.binaryString` = `10110`

I have achieved the above functionality with this:

```
function Binary () {
    var obj = { binaryString: '' };

    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'zero', {
        get: function() {
            obj.binaryString += '0';
            return obj;
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'one', {
        get: function() {
            obj.binaryString += '1';
            return obj;
        }
    });

    return obj;
}

var binary = new Binary();
binary.one.zero.zero.one  // => obj.binaryString becomes '1001'
```

Now I want to log out the completed `binaryString`, plus and `additionalString` which I have accomplished with the code below:

```
// placed inside Binary constructor function
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'log', {
    get: function() {
        return function(additionalString) {
            console.log(obj.binaryString + additionalString);
        };
    }
});
```

So with this current code I can do this:

```
binary.one.zero.one.zero.one.log(' is the answer');
// logs out `10101 is the answer`
```

What I want to do is get rid of the `log` and make the `one` and `zero` methods invokable or not so I can achieve this functionality:

```
binary.one.one.zero.one(' is the result')
// => logs out `1101 is the result`
```

How can I do this?

I believe it would be similar functionality to how [Chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) works:

```
chalk.blue.bold('Hello world!');
// `blue` is not invoked here but it adds the color blue to the style

chalk.blue('Hello world!');
// `blue` IS invoked here.  It adds blue to the style and returns the stylized string
```

Comment: Make `obj` a function instead of a plain object. Give the function the `.binaryString` property. When invoked, the function can get the property via `this.binaryString` or `obj.binaryString`.

Comment: ...like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbk70spw/

Comment: You asked the same question a couple of hours ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43902656/make-a-property-either-invokable-or-not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Make the obj as function , and print what ever you want .

```js
function Binary () {
    var obj = function(msg){ console.log(msg+this.binaryString ) };
    obj.binaryString = ''

    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'zero', {
        get: function() {
            obj.binaryString += '0';
            return obj;
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(obj, 'one', {
        get: function() {
            obj.binaryString += '1';
            return obj;
        }
    });

    return obj;
}

var binary = new Binary();
binary.one.zero.zero.one.zero(" is the result ")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out that what you're doing is a very bad/dangerous idea: abusing read properties to mutate the object itself is asking for trouble.  You may not see it now, but it's going to lead to pain and heartache down the line in the form of difficult-to-find bugs and convoluted patterns.

What you *can* do is, which is not so dangerous, is instead of mutating the object itself, return a new instance of `Binary` with every call to `#one` or `#zero`.  For example:

```
function Binary(s) {
  this.binaryString = s || ''
}
Object.defineProperty(Binary.prototype, 'zero', {
  get: function() {
    return new Binary(this.binaryString + '0')
}})
Object.defineProperty(Binary.prototype, 'one', {
  get: function() {
    return new Binary(this.binaryString + '1')
}})
```

This is the approach taken by Chalk, and will be much safer and less error-prone.

**UPDATE**:

After thinking about your problem, and seeing your question, I think the best approach at all is not to use classes at all.  You can solve this problem with a pure function-based approach.  It's immutable, it's safe, and I believe it's less confusing.  Here it is in ES5:

```
function bin(str) {
  if(!str) str = ''
  function f(msg) { return str + ' ' + msg }
  return Object.defineProperties(f, {
    zero: {
      get: function() {
        return bin(str + '0')
      },
    },
    one: {
      get: function() {
        return bin(str + '1')
      },
    },
  })
}
```

And if you can use ES6 (aka ES2015), you can make it much more compact:

```
function bin(str = '') {
  return Object.defineProperties(msg => `${str} ${msg}`, {
    zero: { get() { return bin(str + '0') } },
    one: { get() { return bin(str + '1') } },
  })
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
bin().one.zero.one.zero('is the answer') // '1010 is the answer'
```

Comment: thank you for the advice.  Would you mind telling me how my code would lead to difficult-to-find-bugs and convoluted patterns?  To me right now it seems pretty straight forward to understand and debug. Is it just a bad practice to do this? Would this functionality actually lead to more bugs?  Thanks.  Also, why are you putting the properties on the `prototype` instead of the object itself?

Comment: Read properties are -- as the name implies -- for reading things, at least by convention (and its a good and reasonable convention).  It would be easy to forget that something that looks like a read property is actually mutating the object.  Furthermore, JavaScript code is rife with automated introspection.  For example, saying `for(p in someBinaryNumber) console.log(someBinaryNumber[p])` would add a 1 and 0 to your number!  Worse, you couldn't predict the order!  Increasingly, people are feeling that mutability is just bad in general.

Comment: As for putting the properties on `prototype`, it's the more "OOP" way to do it, though this is such a weird hybrid example that it's six of one half a dozen of the other.  And OOP is weird in JS in general, and lots of people think you shouldn't do it anyway (shrug).  Certainly I don't write a lot of what would be considered OOP these days.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your feedback!  Thank you!

Comment: With the format that you laid out, how would I achieve the functionality of being able to invoke a property (`binary.one.zero.one(" is the result") // => 10 is the result`) like Dzair outlined in the answer above?